# Nativecript Fontawesome 5 iphone not working

Tags: android, iphone, font-awesome, nativescript

I'm trying to get Font Awesome 5 to work on android but it's not working. Using the https://github.com/NathanWalker/nativescript-ngx-fonticon package.

My folder structure

```
- src
-- assets
-- fonts
-- app
```

The assets folder contains the fontawesome css (font-awesome.css), I've removed everything above the "Font Awesome uses the Unicode Private Use Area (PUA) to ensure screen
 readers do not read off random characters that represent icons" remark.

The fonts folder contains all the fontfiles (eot / svg / ttf / woff / woff2)  I've downloaded from Font Awesome 5 website (fa-brands / fa-regular / fa-solid)

In my main scss file I have a line :

```
.fa {
    font-family: FontAwesome, fontawesome-webfont;
}

.fas {
    font-family: FontAwesome, fa-solid-900;
}
```

In my app.module.ts :

```
import { TNSFontIconModule , TNSFontIconService } from 'nativescript-ngx-fonticon';
TNSFontIconService.debug = true;
```

and import :

```
    TNSFontIconModule.forRoot({
        'fa': './assets/font-awesome.css'
    })
```

Now in my HTML:

```
<Label  class="fas" [text]="'fa-bars' | fonticon" color="#2c0239"></Label>
```

I've also modified my webpack config to copy and watch the src/assets/ folder:

```
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        { from: "assets/**"},
        { from: "fonts/**" },
        { from: "**/*.jpg" },
        { from: "**/*.png" },
    ], { ignore: [`${relative(appPath, appResourcesFullPath)}/**`] }),
```

So when I run this on my iPhone I get [?]

Comment: Try removing `fas` class definition and see if that helps, as they share same name.

Comment: actually the .fas class made it worked on android :)

Answer (score 1):

Finally have it :

```
.fas {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free", fa-solid-900;
}
```

The first one ("Font Awesome 5 Free") is needed for iPhone and fa-solid-900 is needed for Android.

Comment: But can you get both normal and bold to work on iPhone? I've only been able to get one or the other. Android works fine as it uses the fa-regular-400 and fa-regular-900 to find the font.

Comment: "bold" I know what you mean.

Comment: I can’t have bold icons and plain icons in my iphone app, only one or the other

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it because [that](http://%20https://github.com/NathanWalker/nativescript-ngx-fonticon) didn't worked for me.

I'm using Nativescript and VueJs

Version of Font Awesome: **5.4.2**

You will need to following fonts:

```
fa-regular-400
fa-brands-400
fa-solid-900
```

You need to place them `app>fonts`

Add this to `app>app.css`

```
.far {
     font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free', fa-regular-400;
     font-size: 40em;
}

.fab {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Brands', fa-brands-400;
    font-size: 40em;
}

.fas {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free', fa-solid-900;
    font-size: 40em;
}
```

You can change the `font-size`.

#### So how to use in the template?

A few examples:

```
<Label class="fab" :text="'\uf060' | unescape"></Label>
<Label class="fab" :text="'\uf170' | unescape"></Label>
<Label class="fab" :text="'\uf36e' | unescape"></Label>

filters: {
           unescape: v => unescape(v)
       }
```

If you [search an icon](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery) you will see the unicode.
You need to copy that.

Example the [Unicode for moon is](https://fontawesome.com/icons/moon?style=solid) `f186`

So to use it you will need to typ `\u{unicode}` => `\uf186`

it will only work if use the attribute `:text` and the function `unescape`.

### Multi line buttons

```
       <Button class="btn">
            <FormattedString>
                <span class="fas" :text="'\u[ICONCODE]' | unescape" ></span>
                <span :text="'\n [TEXT]' | unescape" ></span>
            </FormattedString>
        </Button>

        filters: {
                   unescape: v => unescape(v)
               }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the Brands and Pro FontAwesome 5 fonts working in NativeScript-Vue, install `nativescript-fonticon`, `npm install nativescript-fonticon --save`, as described in the documentation [Using Fonticons](https://nativescript-vue.org/blog/using-fonticons/),
 and from FontAwesome download both the webfonts and desktop fonts. In the directory `app/fonts` add the `.ttf` files from the `webfonts` directory of the web download. iOS also requires the `.otf` files from the `otfs` directory of the desktop download so add these to the `app/fonts` directory as well and rename the basename of the `.otf` files to match the corresponding basename of the `.ttf` file
[image]

In `app/assets` add the corresponding css files from the `css` directory of the web font download (or the all file).
[image]

Now add the following to `app.scss` (note that light and solid don't work properly without `font-weight` properly defined)

```
.fa {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro", "fa-regular-400";
  font-weight: 400;
}

.fas {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro", "fa-solid-900";
  font-weight: 900;
}

.fab {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Brands", "fa-brands-400";
  font-weight: 400;
}

.fal {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro", "fa-light-300";
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

and the following to `main.ts`

```
import {TNSFontIcon, fonticon} from 'nativescript-fonticon';

TNSFontIcon.debug = true;
TNSFontIcon.paths = {
  // 'fa': './assets/css/all.min.css',
  // 'fal': './assets/css/all.min.css',
  // 'far': './assets/css/all.min.css',
  // 'fas': './assets/css/all.min.css',
  // 'fab': './assets/css/all.min.css',
  'fa': './assets/css/fontawesome.min.css',
  'fal': './assets/css/light.min.css',
  'far': './assets/css/regular.min.css',
  'fas': './assets/css/solid.min.css',
  'fab': './assets/css/brands.min.css'
};
TNSFontIcon.loadCss();

Vue.filter('fonticon', fonticon);
```

Now delete the `platforms` directory to make sure everything gets bundled correctly and you should be good to go. Use it like

```
  <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="top">
    <Label class="fab" :text="'fa-git' | fonticon" />
    <Label class="fal" :text="'fa-plus-square' | fonticon" />
    <Label class="fa" :text="'fa-plus-square' | fonticon" />
    <Label class="fas" :text="'fa-plus-square' | fonticon" />
  </StackLayout>
```

To make things even easier there is plugin [Vue-Fonticon](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-vue-fonticon) that is essentially the following code which I copied into `app/components/FontIcon.vue`

```
<template>
  <Label
    :class="type"
    :color="color"
    :fontSize="size"
    :text="name | fonticon"
    :width="size"
    textAlignment="center"
    @tap="$emit('tap')"
  />
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'FontIcon',
    props: {
      color: {
        type: String,
        default: 'black'
      },
      name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      size: {
        type: [String, Number],
        default: 15,
        validation: s => !isNaN(s)
      },
      type: {
        type: String,
        default: 'fa'
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

To use it, in `main.ts` add

```
import FontIcon from './components/Utility/FontIcon.vue'

Vue.component(FontIcon.name, FontIcon)
```

and use it as

```
  <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="top">
    <FontIcon name="fa-play" size="16" color="red"/>
    <FontIcon name="fa-play" type="fal" size="32" color="green"/>
    <FontIcon name="fa-play" type="fas" size="64" color="blue"/>
    <FontIcon name="fa-git" type="fab" @tap="tapHandler"/>
  </StackLayout>
```