# How to add Font-awesome icon to tabview in Nativescript Vue platform

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, font-awesome, nativescript-vue

I'm trying to use font-awesome icon inside the TabView item.  I am able to use this same code elsewhere in the page and it works fine. It just wont show any icon inside the tabview.

In my main.js:

```
import {TNSFontIcon, fonticon} from 'nativescript-fonticon';


TNSFontIcon.debug = true;
TNSFontIcon.paths = {
  'fa': './assets/css/font-awesome.css',
  'ion': './ionicons.css'
};
TNSFontIcon.loadCss();

Vue.filter('fonticon', fonticon);
```

In App.vue:

```
<TabView class="tab-view" :selectedIndex="selectedIndex" androidTabsPosition="bottom">
  <TabViewItem class="fa" :text="'fa-plane' | fonticon" >
    <Label text="Content for Tab 1"/>
  </TabViewItem>
  <TabViewItem title="Tab 2">
    <Label text="Content for Tab 2" @tap="pretextsTap()" />
  </TabViewItem>
</TabView>
```

I'm using Nativescript Vue platform and couldn't find the example of using font-awesome icon inside the tabview item.  In the first TabViewItem, I was trying to add fa-plane icon to see if I got it right.  It didn't. I look forward to your tip.

Thanks.

Comment: Please go through examples and discussions in this [Github issue](https://github.com/NathanWalker/nativescript-fonticon/issues/15), make sure you do a clean build and your webpack config is updated to include the CSS files.

Comment: [Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53317489/6838936)

Answer (score 1):

Tab view items have a title property, not text. 
Give `:title="'fa-plane' | fonticon"` a shot.