# Use Icon Fonts in TabViewItem - Nativescript-Vue

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I have been searching for a clean way to use Font Icons (iconmoon in my case) for `TabViewItem` but have not found an answer. Does anyone know how to do it?

I am using **NativeScript-Vue**. The ideal way of doing it would be by changing the `iconSource` with the font icon, but it does not work. Something like `:iconSource="String.fromCharCode(0xea0d)"`

The code I am using is the following (instead of `labels` I have `frames` inside each `TabViewItem`).

```
<TabView :selectedIndex="selectedIndex" iosIconRenderingMode="alwaysOriginal">
  <TabViewItem title="Tab 1" iconSource="~/images/icon.png">
    <Label text="Content for Tab 1" />
  </TabViewItem>
  <TabViewItem title="Tab 2" iconSource="~/images/icon.png">
    <Label text="Content for Tab 2" />
  </TabViewItem>
</TabView>
```

Comment: instead of iconSource use fonticon in title

Comment: Did you [tried this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53317489/6838936)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to use font icon on `iconSource`, it would accept only images.

But you could either use font icon on the `title` attribute but that may prevent you from styling your title with a different font Or you could use the [nativescript-vector-icons](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/) which can convert the font icon into image on the fly and apply it to `iconSource`.